# Dataloader relationship issues

Tags: data-loader, salesforce-id

How can data will  be inserted if the records have master or look up relationship? Also how external id  is useful in dataloader

Comment: what is your scenario? You have a list of child record to be inserted and parent record is already in org? Can you explain them?

Comment: If I inserted a record which has master relationship or look up relationship how it was identified in the excel sheet and I deleted what is its impact

Comment: if you have the parent record already in org, you can use id of those parent record in excel sheet and match it with the lookup field. Do you have them in org? or both parent and child are in excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using upsert option data loader.

To elaborate further let’s consider lookup relationship between Account & client (custom object) and lookup relation is exist on account object with label client__c. I simulate a situation where it needs upsert data in account object with valid information for the client__c field.

Step 2a. of upsert operation need to select a field to match record. If you select external ID you can Upsert several times without duplicating the data. If it is record id duplicate records can be created due to subsequent Upsert operation with same data.

Step 2b. of upsert- select external id for each related object. For my lookup relationship on account .it will display as client__r. You need to select external ID for required relationship fields. For my client__r field I have selected my external ID BE_ID__c external ID field. Further, I mark this fields as unique field.

Field Mapping : your data set need to have a column (Ex: Client ID) with values for external ID. This value need to be unique.  As per my example this client ID column need to map this relationship column. On top of your field mapping section you can see database fields, a field new field is available for relationship column. As per my example I need to map as following,

Client ID column on excel with relationship field client__r:BE_ID__c. during upsert operation it will find salesforce record id for client records from client object for  record on Account object where my client__c look field is exist. Same concept is applicable for Master detail relationships.